# Open GL Rectangle

Tags: android, opengl-es

I need a little bit help with this code... I've done it following developers.android, but it still isn't work! Problem with displaying. There is only green screen with no any rectangle. Can someone help me? Thanks!:)

```
public class Paddle 
{
    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;
    private int mProgram;

    public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){

        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

        return shader;
    }

    private final String vertexShaderCode =
            "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "  gl_Position = vPosition;" +
                    "}";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
            "precision mediump float;" +
                    "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
                    "}";


    static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;

    static float squareCoords[] = {
            -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
            0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f };

    private short drawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 };

    private float color[] = {1, 1, 1, 1};

    private int mPositionHandle;
    private int mColorHandle;

    private final int vertexCount = squareCoords.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
    private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

    public Paddle()
    {

        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(squareCoords.length * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(squareCoords);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocate(drawOrder.length * 2);
        dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
        drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
        drawListBuffer.position(0);

        int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
                vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
                fragmentShaderCode);
        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader);
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);

    }

    public void draw()
    {
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

        mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");
        GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 4, color, 0);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you used `glGetShaderiv` and `glGetShaderInfoLog` to check for shader compilation errors? That's likely to be more reliable than trying to spot by eye.